# JavaScript Puzzle about internationally-known fairy-tale

Tags: computer-puzzle

**Hello world!**
Learning OOP I came up on this Puzzle.
We can call this *JPuzzle*
Kinda simple, but no-one gave the right answer yet.
Here is the JPuzzle:

---

- `_=(..._)=>_`
- It is JavaScript
- It is a true form
- "Go there don’t know where bring it don’t know what"

---

**What is it?**

P.S. The Puzzle is not about the syntax, or how it works, or what it does. Think different.

Comment: Can we get a hint?

Comment: @Ankit It is connected with OOP in some way.

Comment: Is “true from” a typo, or a cryptic hint?

Comment: @deceze I can not give any more hints, unfortunately.

Comment: @CHERNOMOR, I know from java that => is something in java OOP called a lambda expression. I don't know if it is the same in Js.

Comment: Also I may be wrong but if I remember correct "..." means unknown amount of variables

Comment: @Ankit Yes, I'll clarify syntax, since it's not the goal of the puzzle to read it. This function returns an array of arguments. You can test it in browser dev tools by writting smth like that in Console tab:
`_=(..._)=>_;`
`console.log(_('I wanna test JPuzzle', 'I really want', 123));`

Comment: Hi is this related to the story of `Pinocchio` ?

Comment: @Swati Nope, maybe there is similar inea in Pinocchio, but I didn't have that tale in mind creating this puzzle.

Comment: @deceze Is “true from” a typo, or a cryptic hint? – Its a mistake :)
Not a true from - a "true form"!
I've fixed it already. Sorry.

Comment: Can we get hint  ?

Comment: @CHERNOMOR, to explain the question & answer downvotes: it's not clear how anyone could get the answer with only the information provided. That means this boils down to a "guess what I'm thinking" puzzle; such puzzles are considered poor-quality by this community.

Answer (score -5):

The answer is - Parametric Polymorphism.
My functional expression above can take any kind and any number of inputs(arguments).
And will simply return all of them as an array.
But, can we solve such task any other way?
"Go there don’t know where bring it don’t know what" - is not "bring me anything".
So, random return is not the answer.
If we go back to the fairy-tale, we'll see, that our hero brought some entity with no form, which returns anything you ask. You say food, it returns food, e.t.c.
Parametric Polymorphism itself, as a concept, is what the king asked our hero to deliver.

Comment: So what specific "internationally well-known fairy tale" is the answer? Or is this just a generic fairy tale?

Comment: My 6yo disagrees about this being a fairy tale.

Comment: @bobble The name is "Go there don’t know where bring it don’t know what". I thought the this tale itself is international, but I may be wrong, if this name corresponds only to russian tale. But, There must be international tales with that concept.

Comment: @IanMacDonald He might be right.

Comment: @bobble From googling, that name itself seems to be a Russian fairytale. I'm still confused by the rest of the answer though.